# R - ggplot2 - Visualize deviations from base model

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, statistics

```
base = c(1.84,3.92,1.67,1.12,1.63,.62,.59)
e1 = c(.61,1.47,1.68,1.95,1.64,.61,.72)
e2 = c(.64,7.08,1.67,1.12,1.44,.46,.76)
e3 = c(.64,4.47,1.68,2.04,1.45,.4,1.35)
e4 = c(.78,1.61,1.62,1.09,1.46,.66,.76)
e5 = c(.78,.99,1.62,2.32,1.46,.73,.52)

df = data.frame(base,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5)
```

I have the following parameters from a baseline model and 5 other exploratory models. I'm trying to do as much job as possible for the reader so I'm thinking about going beyond tabling this out.

Is there a way to plot this in ggplot in a way that would show deviations from the estimates of the baseline model? I can't think of any as there are 6 values.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by deviations from the estimates of the baseline model? Do you want to get the difference of the means of the others from the mean of `base`?

Comment: just the values – let base values be 0 and the rest be (base-ei)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for. Here I calculate the difference between each model & the `base` model using `purrr::map_df`. After that I convert the result to long format for plotting w/ `ggplot2`

```r
library(tidyverse)

base = c(1.84,3.92,1.67,1.12,1.63,.62,.59)
e1 = c(.61,1.47,1.68,1.95,1.64,.61,.72)
e2 = c(.64,7.08,1.67,1.12,1.44,.46,.76)
e3 = c(.64,4.47,1.68,2.04,1.45,.4,1.35)
e4 = c(.78,1.61,1.62,1.09,1.46,.66,.76)
e5 = c(.78,.99,1.62,2.32,1.46,.73,.52)

df = data.frame(base, e1, e2, e3, e4, e5)

# calculate colwise differences
df %>% 
  map_df( ~ (. - base)) %>% 
  select(-base) %>% 
  # create id for each number
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  # convert to long format
  gather(key = "model", value = "diff", -id) -> df_dif

# plot the differences
ggplot(df_dif, aes(x = id, y = diff)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = model), position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(~ model) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-06 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks, this is a cool solution! I'm just not sure whether it wouldnt confuse the reader. I'll probably won't add it because it would require a lot of explanation but I want you to know that I appreciate your solution.

Comment: You're welcome! Are your model results timeseries or different replicates?

Comment: Replicates, basically. I have a preregistered specification which didn't work at all so I'm trying to toy with the model in different ways to get my hand on the problem (and the underlying structure of the data). That second parameter's behaviour is pretty fishy, for example, which shows that the items might have been too difficult for people

Comment: Gotcha. You might find this [data visualization book](http://serialmentor.com/dataviz/) useful when you have more results in the future